# AS3 - Loading multiple videos into the same container - addChild removeChild

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

This is a function that loads a specific video into a MovieClip container at 0.0 using a video class.

```
public var mainVideo:SimpleVideo;

public function loadVideo(videoString:String) :void{
    mainVideo = new
    SimpleVideo("videos/"+videoString+".flv","",true,video_container.positionMc);
    video_container.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,controlVideoPlayer);
    addChild(mainVideo);
    trace('adding new video to container');
}
```

I'd like to preferably check, each time a video is loaded, to see if there already is another video loaded. And if there is, then remove it, and add the new video.

I've tried using `removeChild()` in a variety of ways, but it doesn't seem to work correctly.

Would I use `removeChild(mainVideo)`? `video_container.removeChild(mainVideo)`?
And how would I be able to check if there was already an existing `mainVideo`?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

-Update-
If I try and use `removeChild(mainVideo)` I get this error:

> TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter child must be non-null.
>  at
>   flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/removeChild()
>    at
>   Main/removeVideo()    at MethodInfo-127()

Comment: Where are you adding the `removeChild(mainVideo)`? Can you update your code?

Answer (score 0):

If you add the video into a container movieclip rather than onto stage, and that container only has just one instance of SimpleVideo in its display list at a time, you could do:

```
if( myVideoContainer.numChildren > 0 )
{
    myVideoContainer.removeChild( myVideoContainer.getChildAt( 0 ) );
}
```

A bigger issue though is how the SimpleVideo class you are using cleans itself up.  Most video classes have a cleanup or kill function that removes the listeners and cleans up the netStream.  I would think you'd need to call something like that as well as removing the video instance from the container.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this respone may help you

--> Would I use `removeChild(mainVideo)` ? `video_container.removeChild(mainVideo)` ?

you should use `removeChild` function but you need to know who is the parent of mainVideo and call this function of his parent, in your case, I think, `video_container` is not the parent because is a variable near mainVideo and you add mainVideo to the instance of the class which has `loadVideo` function

sometimes you can use `mainVideo.parent.removeChild(mainVideo)`, not the best approach but it works, it's better to know who is the parent and call function `removeChild()` explicitly on that "parent"

--> would I be able to check if there was already an existing mainVideo?

well, you can do a simple `if(mainVideo != null) { .. }` because in function loadVideo you create new instances each time, that means if you called at least one time this function then `if` condition should be true that means you have already an existing mainVideo

--> `TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter child must be non-null.`

that means your mainVideo is not instantiated, because I guess you have not called `loadVideo()` yet, that's why @putvande asked you to provide more code, we need to see where and when you call `removeChild()`